# CoreData FetchRequest with NSPredicate comparison on transformable

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch an object CoreDataTypeA that contains a transformable type, TransType. I want to get the object that matches the transformable type that I pass in to the NSPredicate. When I return the code below I always get a return of 0.

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TransType == %@", transType)
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<CoreDataTypeA> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoreDataTypeA")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        let requestReturn = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        guard requestReturn.count != 1 else {
            return 0.0 // Always returns THIS !!!!
        }

        let fetchedObj = requestReturn[0]
        print("object Value: \(fetchedObj.value)")
        return fetchedObj.objValue

    } catch {
        print("Error, not found!")
        return 0.0
    }
```

Edit: Changed the code to remove the guard statement to make this easier:

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TransType == %@", transType)
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<CoreDataTypeA> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoreDataTypeA")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        let requestReturn = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    if(requestReturn.count != 0) {
        let fetchedObj = requestReturn[0]
        print("object Value: \(fetchedObj.value)")
        return fetchedObj.objValue
    } else {
        return 0.0 // STILL RETURNS HERE
    }

    } catch {
        print("Error, not found!")
        return 0.0
    }
```

Comment: Is the property named "TransType"? Have you checked the spelling?

Comment: the property is named TransType and I have checked the spelling.

Comment: What's the type of transType you're passing to the predicate?

Comment: Is that guard condition correct?  Don't you need == instead of !=

Comment: @hacker2007 TransType is a custom class. I have overrides on the isEqual if that helps

Comment: @pbasdf The guard condition is if it returns zero items. Fetch limit is 1. Unless I am missing something here.

Comment: The else clause is executed if the condition is false.  `requestReturn.count != 1` is false if `requestReturn.count = 1`.  So the else clause is executed if your fetch returns one item.

Comment: @pbasdf changed the code to remove the guard and still no dice.